# Flutter Gesture Detector ontap throws Stack Overflow error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a controller in a controller.dart file and I'm using it in view.dart file to login a user but clicking on the gesture detector throws a stack overflow error. I've tried many things and looked all over but can't seem to understand what's wrong

**controller.dart**

```
class SigninController extends GetxController {
  // SigninController();
  final state = SigninController();
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['openid']);
  // ignore: unused_element

  Future<void> handleSignIn(String type) async {
    //number 1 = email, number 2 = google, number 3 = facebook, number 4 = apple, number 5 = phone
    try {
      if (type == "phone") {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("Logging in with phone");
        }
      } else if (type == "google") {
        var user = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
        if (user != null) {
          String? displayName = user.displayName;
          String email = user.email;
          String id = user.id;
          String photo = user.photoUrl ?? "assets/icons/google.png";
          LoginRequestEntity loginPanelListRequestEntity = LoginRequestEntity();
          loginPanelListRequestEntity.avatar = photo;
          loginPanelListRequestEntity.name = displayName;
          loginPanelListRequestEntity.avatar = photo;
          loginPanelListRequestEntity.open_id = id;
          loginPanelListRequestEntity.type = 2;
        }
      } else {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("Login type not defined");
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Login error $e");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**concerned widget from view.dart file**

```
Widget _buildThirdPartyLogin(String loginType, String logo) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => controller.handleSignIn(loginType),
      child: Container(
        width: 295.w,
        height: 44.h,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.h),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: AppColors.primaryBackground,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                  spreadRadius: 1,
                  blurRadius: 2,
                  offset: const Offset(0, 1))
            ]),
        child: Row(children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.w, top: 5.w, bottom: 5.w),
            child: Image.asset("assets/icons/$logo.png"),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.w),
            child: Text(
              "Sign up with $loginType",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: AppColors.primaryText,
                  fontSize: 16.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Error produced**

```
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#4f5fc
    debugOwner: GestureDetector
    state: possible
    won arena
    finalPosition: Offset(205.4, 249.4)
    finalLocalPosition: Offset(170.0, 21.2)
    button: 1
    sent tap down
```

Comment: try to remove fixed sizing with `w`,`h`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

---

**Changes are sizing parameter that you have used**

---

```
Widget _buildThirdPartyLogin(String loginType, String logo) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => controller.handleSignIn(loginType),
      child: Container(
        width: 295,
        height: 44,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: AppColors.primaryBackground,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                  spreadRadius: 1,
                  blurRadius: 2,
                  offset: const Offset(0, 1))
            ]),
        child: Row(children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, top: 5, bottom: 5),
            child: Image.asset("assets/icons/$logo.png"),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
            child: Text(
              "Sign up with $loginType",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: AppColors.primaryText,
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```